# Increasing speed performance of a pixel color checker function in Python

Tags: python, performance

I am writing a python function that checks a region of the windows desktop environment for a certain pixel color, and if this color meets a certain criteria, then python returns true.

The problem is, optimally I need this pixel check to be occurring at a timing frequency of 100ms or less. I have done a very crude method of measuring timing performance, and it appears I am getting a "refresh rate" of no better than ~250milliseconds.

Is there any possible way to improve the performance of this script and/or more accurately measure timing?

Code attached below:

```
import win32gui
import time

def get_pixel_colour(i_x, i_y):
    i_desktop_window_id = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
    i_desktop_window_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(i_desktop_window_id)
    long_colour = win32gui.GetPixel(i_desktop_window_dc, i_x, i_y)
    i_colour = int(long_colour)
    return (i_colour & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 8) & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 16) & 0xff)

def main():
    for x in range(20):
        t1 = time.time()
        x = get_pixel_colour(25, 1024)
        y = str(x)
        if y == "(255, 255, 255)":
            print "True"
        else:
            print "Not True"
        t2 = time.time()
        print t2 - t1 #To calculate time

main()
```

Comment: why do you convert the pixel to string and compare that string? That's much slower than directly comparing numeric values

Answer (score 1):

No need to split the RGB components. That takes some time. And then the 3 conversion for those components from int to string take much more time. Just return the pixel value as is

```
def get_pixel_colour(i_x, i_y):
    i_desktop_window_id = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
    i_desktop_window_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(i_desktop_window_id)
    return win32gui.GetPixel(i_desktop_window_dc, i_x, i_y)
```

Then in main just compare the RGB value directly

```
for x in range(20):
    t1 = time.time()
    if get_pixel_colour(25, 1024) == 0xFFFFFF
        print "True"
    else:
        print "Not True"
    t2 = time.time()
    print t2 - t1 #To calculate time
```